# Trying to find out why the "For/Next error is happeniong?

Tags: excel, vba

I am self-taught and still trying to figure things out... saying that I can't figure out why its saying there is no "for" when I have it. This is for the results Userform I have created. When you hit the next button, it searches the variable again but after the first (Thats what I want it to happen, but it doesn't work either). Trying to get the loop to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim Variable As Variant
Dim LineItem As Variant
Dim DeptID As Variant
Dim Fund As Variant
Dim ProjID As Variant
Dim Equip As Variant
Dim IMEI As Variant
Dim Pin As Variant
Dim Device As Variant
Dim Ordered As Variant
Dim Upgraded As Variant
Dim Name As Variant
Dim EMail As Variant
Dim Password As Variant
Dim c As Range

Variable = Range("P1000").value

Set c = Cells.Find(what:=Variable)

i = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name

Unload Me

For Each c In Range(i).Cells

    Cells.FindNext(after:=c).Select

    If Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then

        Range("P1:AC2").Clear

        Search_Button.Show

    ElseIf Cells.FindNext(after:=c).Select Then

       ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion).Copy

        Range("P2").PasteSpecial

        LineItem = Range("p2").value
        DeptID = Range("q2").value
        Fund = Range("r2").value
        ProjID = Range("s2").value
        Equip = Range("t2").value
        IMEI = Range("u2").value
        Pin = Range("v2").value
        Device = Range("w2").value
        Ordered = Range("x2").value
        Upgraded = Range("y2").value
        Name = Range("z2").value
        EMail = Range("aa2").value
        Password = Range("ab2").value
        
        Range("P1:AC2").Clear

        Results.TextBox14 = Variable

        Results.Textbox1 = LineItem
        Results.TextBox2 = DeptID
        Results.TextBox3 = Fund
        Results.TextBox4 = ProjID
        Results.TextBox5 = Equip
        Results.TextBox6 = IMEI
        Results.TextBox7 = Pin
        Results.TextBox8 = Device
        Results.TextBox9 = Ordered
        Results.TextBox10 = Upgraded
        Results.TextBox11 = Name
        Results.TextBox12 = EMail
        Results.TextBox13 = Password

        Results.Show

    Else: Exit For
    
    
End If

Next

Range("P1:AC2").Clear



End Sub
```

Comment: If you indent your code it's going to be much easier to see where the problem is.  It's much more difficult to read/maintain code which is not indented.

Comment: Having said that you have `Unload Me` near the top of your code - is that meant to be there?   Also `'For Each c In Range(i).Cells` is probably not intended to be commented out?

Comment: Tim - OK, I tabbed it as I think it should go. First question on a place like this.  The unload me is a reference to the search Userform I created that has the original Variable. I uncommented the "For" start. No change

Comment: OK, I fixed it.  I did end if - exit for - next. It still doesn't loop but I got rid of that error I came here for. Will keep working on it. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is your desire but the Exit For statement will jump out of the For Each loop once it gets there the first time.  And effectively never repeat the loop.  If you debug the code line-by-line (F8) you'll see what's happening.  You would only typically use the Exit For statement within some condition inside the For loop.  For example if you were looping through cells to find a certain value then once you find it could call Exit For to stop the loop from continuing to run unnecessarily.

Comment: Grant- Thank you. I didn't know that. It did that before on a previous iteration of this code and I couldn't figure out how to make it quit. Thank you.

Comment: This link will help with indenting if you need:  https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/

Comment: Darren - Thank you. I didn't know about that. I updated my code with the new indents.

Comment: Figured it out. Completely revamped it to a Boolean loop.